# Are some files (like pictures) erased when re-launching a cordova iOS app from xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm working on a Cordova app for iOS and I've run into something strange. I have the files in the app being stored in persistent storage (I'm sure of that). If I hit the run button in xcode while the app is running on my iPhone, it will relaunch the app after building my changes. Now, what's strange is that some of my data that was saved in the app to a file is there, but pictures are no longer there. However, if I manually force close and then re-open the app on my iPhone (without touching anything in xcode), the pictures will still be there so I know they are persisting fine when the app closes.

Something about launching the app from xcode is removing those picture files.

Anyone aware of data loss occurring (files) when testing apps in xcode?

Comment: Where are you storing your "Picture files"? Is it NSDocumentDirectory ?? iOS will not delete sandbox contents when you are installing an app on top of an existing one. Sandbox is removed only when app is deleted. Little more clarity on how you are storing the files would help us to suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: I am storing the files in the cordova.file.dataDirectory, which the cordova file plugin states as being in the Library/NoCloud directory.

Comment: Any other info that would be helpful?

Comment: Can you print and see what is the file path Cordova file plugin is pointing to?

Comment: The path is file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[RANDOM CHARACTERS]/Library/NoCloud/[MyFolder]/myfilename.jpg

Comment: @Sam i believe the path from /[RANDOM CHARACTERS]/ will be recreated every time the app rebuilds and launches. Definitely the plugin is not wiping the data for sure as per this link - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#ios-file-system-layout

Comment: That makes sense, except for the fact that some text-based data that I save to .json files next to the images still loads fine. :S

Comment: I just did a test with this with an actual app in the Apple store. It is still happening. After an app update, the pictures disappear but other data files are still loading. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I found the problem. The images were actually not being lost, it's just that I had saved a full path to those images, which became incorrect after an update. You have to construct a path at runtime using cordova.file.dataDirectory.

Comment: @Sam Thats what i have mentioned in my comment stating that the path will be recreated everytime the app is build and relaunched. have posted my answer. Accept if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, the plugin dont tamper the data. The path gets changes dynamically on every app rebuild. The complete path is changed every time when the app is rebuilt and relaunched. Ensure that you dont rely on the complete path for any business logic implementation.

Create your own path relative to the `cordova.file.dataDirectory` so that the path remains constant irrespective of the app update and the business logic remains intact.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, and it worked like a charm. You were right. I was just confused because I was not saving a full path reference to the text files, only the images, so that's why they only were not showing up. The best way to debug this was just to view the app folder on the phone from Xcode, then it all became clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam Glad you cracked it. Cheers